# Unable to understand the logic of below output:-

Tags: multithreading

```
public class Test implements Runnable
{
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.printf("%d",3);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Test());
        thread.start();  //line10
        System.out.printf("%d",1);
        thread.join();
        System.out.printf("%d",2);
    }

}
```

In the above code, at line 10 thread.start(); should spawn a new thread and hence run() should be called.Hence, Output should be 312 but instead on running the program, I got 132.

Answer (score 0):

Main thread and new thread created are running in parallel , so if main thread reaches the line 11 first you will see 1 and then if new thread reaches its statement first you will get 3  and then 1

Answer (score 0):

Start put thread to runnable mode, it does NOT mean call run method directly somewhere inside start, after start (), it counts on scheduler to finally run the thread, so 312 132 123 all are acceptable result.

Comment: Each time I get the same result 132. So, a little confused when the run() is exactly called.

Comment: It depends on the environment, the point is that all result are acceptable or consider correct, so in your environment always 132 may due to lack of CPU free core,  and when you use print system method, AFAIK there is a implicit lock to guarantee the print out result not been interleaved by multiple thread.  You'd better check out jcstress to properly test multithread behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The very nature of multi-threading is that you cannot usually guarantee or predict which line gets executed before another if they are being executed concurrently.

In this case it may be a little predictable however. Line 10 will need to access the memory (heap) allocation of the `Test` type, and *then* access the memory location of the `run()` method, and *then* execute the `run()` method, which *then* runs `printf` within that function.

Depending on what language you use, this may vary in optimization; but regardless of how well optimized that is, it will still always be slower than running the very next line after the `thread.start()` which prints `1` immediately after line 10 without waiting.